# Searching for Values in Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

The part I am having trouble with is after the dashes. I need to search the 2 dimensional array for two user inputted numbers. They way I have it, it always says that the values are present, and it does not specify the index the number is at correctly.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class labActivityArrays{

public static void main(String[] args){

String rowS;
rowS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of rows: ");
int row =  Integer.parseInt(rowS);
String columnS;
columnS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of columns: ");
int column = Integer.parseInt(columnS);

String initialS;
initialS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Initial value: ");
int initial =  Integer.parseInt(initialS);

int[][] arr = new int [row][column];

int temp = initial; 

for(int i=0; i < row; i++){
  for(int j=0; j < column; j++){
     arr[i][j] = temp;
     temp += 1;
  }
}

for(int i=0; i < row; i++){
  for(int j=0; j < column; j++){
     System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}

String check1S;
check1S = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("First value to check for: ");
int check1 =  Integer.parseInt(check1S);

String check2S;
check2S = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Second value to check for: ");
int check2 =  Integer.parseInt(check2S);
```

//-------------------------------------------------

```
boolean found = false;    

int i = 0;
int j = 0;

//for the first value
for(i = 0; i < row; i++){
  for(j=0; j < column; j++){
     if(arr[i][j] == check1){
        found = true;      
        break;
     }
  }
}

if(found){
  System.out.println("Found " + check1 + " at index [" + i + "][" + j + "].");
}
else{
  System.out.println(check1 + " is not in this array.");
}

//for the second value
for(i = 0; i < row; i++){
  for(j=0; j < column; j++){
     if(arr[i][j] == check2){
        found = true;      
        break;
     }
  }
}

if(found){
  System.out.println("Found " + check2 + " at index [" + i + "][" + j + "].");
}
else{
  System.out.println(check2 + " is not in this array.");
}


}
}
```

This is my new code after the dash:

```
boolean found = false;
int i = -1;
int j = -1;

//for the first value  
while(!found && i++ < row){
  j = -1;
  while(!found && j++ < column){
     found = (arr[i][j] == check1);
  }
}

if(found){
  System.out.println("Found " + check1 + " at index [" + i + "][" + j + "].");
}
else{
  System.out.println(check1 + " is not in this array.");
}

//for the second value

while(!found && i++ < row){
  j = -1;
  while(!found && j++ < column){
     found = (arr[i][j] == check2);
  }
}

if(found){
  System.out.println("Found " + check2 + " at index [" + i + "][" + j + "].");
}
else{
  System.out.println(check2 + " is not in this array.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `break` only breaks the inner loop. The outer one keeps going.

Try with:

```
int i = -1;
int j = -1;
while(!found && ++i < row) {
    j = -1;
    while(!found && ++j < column) {
        found = (arr[i][j] == check);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for the first value, but the second value will say the first value's index location. And if the first value is not in the array, this error pops up: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at labActivityArrays.main(labActivityArrays.java:85)

Comment: For the second value, you have to redo everything: ``found = false; i = -1; j = -1;``

Comment: You have an exception because you did ``i++`` instead of ``++i``